# Volume form preserved by the action of $\mathrm{PGL(n+1, \mathbb{R}})$ on $\mathbf{P}^n(\mathbb{C}) \setminus \mathbf{P}^n(\mathbb{R}) $?

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions

I know this is quite an elementary question but I am not an expert in Lie theory.

Does the action of $\mathrm{PGL(n+1, \mathbb{R}})$ on $\mathbf{P}^n(\mathbb{C}) \setminus \mathbf{P}^n(\mathbb{R}) $ preserve a natural volume form?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Just check the stabilizer subgroup.